# Can we have a chat cast around a Designer?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Can we have chat casts with professional designers?

For example we pick a certain technique in photoshop or a certain element in design and we pick the brain of the designer for an hour (or a play by play of how that designer would go about it)?

Would Jin (and other designers) be up for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd certainly be up for that. Given how very quiet the chat area generally is, it might give us a way to increase participation. If there's one thing lacking in the site currently -- it's inherent in the SE model, I think -- it's interaction. Time zones are a bit of a hurdle for real-time chat, but better something than nothing.

It would likely be more interesting and more useful if several designers participated in any given chat, rather than one. Everyone I know has his or her own way of approaching a given design challenge, and once you start talking Photoshop techniques, where there are a minimum of 10 ways to do almost anything, the more folks who are involved, the better.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be happy to do this! I agree with Alan that it'd be nice to have multiple designers involved.

Answer (score 2):

I bet if we ask nicely, we could get Jin, the SE designer, to do a chat with us. It could be a nice stepping stone. I'll ask around, see if we can get Jin in sometime. Anyone have a preference for what time to do it?

Comment: Speaking personally, which is the only way I know how to speak, after the New Year would be best. We're up to our ears in project deadlines until early January.

Comment: As for time, I prefer to avoid the 6 am to Noon (PST - UTC -8) time slot. Other than that I'm usually around, lo, even unto the wee hours. :)