# Promotional Grants

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

So, many other newer sites have been getting a boost with promotional grants. One common scheme is as follows (See also [this SFF meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/98)).

1. Select a topic of the week, including future topics. Topics are typically chosen by SE staff, but nominations are taken from the community.
2. During that week, any question about the topic is eligible for a random drawing. (Question must not be closed, and have positive votes)
3. A winner is randomly chosen from the available questions, and the winner gets a prize from Amazon, up to $50. The prize must be related to Graphic Design in some way.

Do you think that such a method could help promote this site?

Comment: Please note that if you do this kind of promotion, you'll need to ask Community Team explicitly to sponsor the contest -- that is, email us a request for sponsorship. :D

Comment: @Aarthi: I figured as much, but I figured I'd ask the community first if they liked the idea;-) Besides, I figured someone from the Community Team would find this post anyways;-)

Comment: Haha, never just figure that -- we're notoriously apt to simply overlook posts like this! :P

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem as useful for site promotion on GD as it would be in some of the other SEs, but that's a personal point of view (i.e., I wouldn't be much interested, but, as Farray observed the other day, I'm an outlier!). Then, too, without any disrespect to the SE staff, I think Jin would be the only one who'd have much of an idea of useful topics to select.

Two ideas that might work to attract users are the earlier suggestion of a [designer chat cast](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235/can-we-have-a-chat-cast-around-a-designer) and some kind of equivalent to Photography's [photo of the week](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes), perhaps a "design of the week." Questions might spring from featured designs ("Why is this color choice effective?" "How is this toning effect achieved?").

Comment: I like rolling in a design of the week into a chat-cast -- have the previous week's winning designer talk about what inspired him/her, what elements he/she found most challenging to put together, how the audience factored into the design, etc.

Comment: Point of interest, the staff doesn't have to chose the topic. I don't think it'd be much of a stretch for someone such as Alan choosing the topic, so long as he agrees to not be eligible for winning the prize or something similar.

Comment: Erm... well, I'm not much (okay, not *at all*) in favor of a design contest. Good designers don't design with contests or awards in mind (corollary: work that wins an Addy or a Clio  very often hasn't increased the client's revenue one bit, so was a waste of time and money). There's no compelling reason to restrict "design of the week" to user-created designs, either. We all learn from the great work, and the mistakes, of others.